# Schengen Country Consulates In Atlantic Canada?

Tags: schengen, canada, schengen-visas, consulates

I am planning to apply for Schengen visa for a visit any European country within Schengen region. I am currently living in Moncton, New Brunswick, Canada. I have Indian passport.

My problem is to my research all the embassies or consulates that issue visas and require interview for Biometrics are in Montreal or Ottawa which is 1000km from where i live.

Are there any Schengen country consulates that issue visas situated in Halifax, Canada or Atlantic Canada?

Comment: Embassies are located in a country's capital; consulates (subordinate diplomatic posts) are located elsewhere...if at all. Schengen country embassies will be located only in Ottawa. You're looking for consulates.

Comment: Note that "visa shopping" is frowned upon. You should apply for a visa from the country you actually have a reason to visit, not the one that is "most convenient" for you.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica in OP's case,  visa application centres that can receive applications should probably be included as well.

Comment: You can find all consular posts in Canada using [this page](https://w05.international.gc.ca/Protocol-Protocole/Consular-Consulats.aspx?lang=eng). However, not all consular posts will be able to process visa applications. For instance, France has a consulate in Moncton, but it redirects to Montréal for visa applications.

Comment: For French type C Schengen visas, most applications need to go through VFS service centres instead of the consulates. It might be worth a trip to Toronto with Swoop (as low as ~$160 roundtrip) or Flair (if they restart Moncton service later).

Comment: Can whoever downvoted explain? I don’t think this question implies visa shopping.

Comment: I am not doing any sort of "visa shopping". I really want to go to any country in Europe and no priority. But on the same hand, i dont want to spend 600-800 CAD to go to Montreal to just apply for visa. And thanks @zhantongz, yeah swoop will be really good option too.